# Code execution step by step (synchronous)

Tags: function, call, execution, synchronous

I just have two (see below) lines of code in my `index.html`. I want to execute the first line BEFORE the second line will be executed. How can I do/ensure that? Currently, "undefined" will be apprear in the console for `dataDB`, because the function getDataFunction() takes some time.

```
var dataDB = getDataFunction(afterDate, toDate, afterTime, toTime);
console.log("Content of dataDB: " + dataDB);
```

Probably an easy question for you :-) I appreciate your help!

**UPDATE: getDataFunction()**
This function just get some data (collection+json) from a server with d3 (data driven document)...The parameters are used to identify the data of interest (time frame).

```
function getDataFunction(afterDate, toDate, afterTime, toTime){

    d3.json("http://server...", function(error, data){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(data);

            dataDB = data.collection.items;
            console.log(dataDB);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: probably something to do with the content of you getDataFunction. You'd need to give a bit more info on what you are doing there. Probably an ajax call that is set to go asynchronously. it would explain the behaviour.

Comment: As you see above, I've updated the origin question with additional information about the getDataFunction().

Answer (score 0):

[D3 api reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json)

It says in the api reference the post is indeed done asychronously, thus the execution of the rest of the code proceeds (in this case console.log) there are no decent ways to make javascript wait. The best thing to do is to redesign it that your callback function takes care of whatever needs to come next.

Comment: Ok, I see. If I execute `console.log("Content of dataDB: " + dataDB);` in the else statement of the function, it works. How should I redesign that in the callback function? Do you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that d3.json call is performed async. So the call executes and when the awnser retruns, the function you created as the callback(the if/else) is executed. Because of the async nature it will start to do this in the background and the rest of the code is executed while the json call is still being performed(hence the undefined log msg).

So whatevery you want to do next, it has to be initiated in the callback function as there is no decent way of making javascript wait for it. What you can do is put a function call in your callback to start the next one if it needs to wait for it.